# Updated entity adds new row to database

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am trying to update entities using ajax but its adds a new row instead to update the existing one.

**My entities:**

- Category
- Product
- Subcategory

**Relations**:

*Category* `ManyToMany` *Product*

*Category* `OneToMany` *Subcategory*

**Category Entity**

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Test\CoreBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="categories", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Groups({"public", "admin"})
     */
    protected $products;



public function setProducts( $products) {
        $this->products= new ArrayCollection($products->toArray());
        return $this;
    }
```

**Product Entity**

```
  /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Test\CoreBundle\Entity\Category", mappedBy="products" )
     * @Exclude()
     */
    protected $categories;
```

**Controller**

```
 $toSave  = $this->get('request')->getContent();


      $s =  $serializer->deserialize($toSave, Test\CoreBundle\Entity\Category, 'json');


                if ($s->getId() > 0) {


                    $category= $em->getRepository('TestCoreBundle:Category)->findOneBy(['id' => $s->getId()]);

                    $category->setName($s->getName());
                    $category->setIsDisabled($s->getIsDisabled());
                    $category->setIsPrivate($s->getIsPrivate());    
                    $category->setQuestions($s->getCategories());

                    $em->persist($category);
                    $em->flush();
                }
```

**Problem:**

This code adds new products to database, I want to update the existing records.

**Things I tried:**

- Replaced `persist` with `merge`, made no difference.
- Removed `persist`, same result

Comment: remove `$em->persist($category);`  and try `$em->flush($category);`

Comment: @tzafar same problem

Comment: remove `cascade={"persist"}` from `ManyToMany` relationship in Category Entity and remove `$em->persist($category);` and try `$em->flush($category);`

Comment: throws exception: `A new entity was found through the relationship Test\CoreBundle\Entity\Category#products that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: . To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).`

Comment: You need to tell jms serializer how to deserialize the products from category. Try `ArrayCollection<Product>`. More: http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#type

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem the following way:

1) I replaced `persist` with `merge`.

```
  $em->merge($category);
  $em->flush();
```

2) Changed the cascade option from persist to merge

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Test\CoreBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="categories", cascade={"merge"})
     * @Groups({"public", "admin"})
     */
    protected $products;
```